# I cannet get post data to echo on a different page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a register.php page, this has the html form for user input, this then posts to itself where php validates the input, that all works as I wanted. I can echo the data after the validation without issue, However when I add redirection using header redirect to register.inc.php and then try to echo the post data from the register.inc.php page it wont do it, almost as if the data isnt being posted to the register.inc.php file, but, if i include the register.inc.php in the register.php page it will echo the data on the register.php page which surely suggests the post data is being sent, ultimately im looking to enter this data into a data base but obviously if the post data isnt being seen i wont be able to, I have tried a session start which didnt work and I dont seem to be able to resolve this by any research i have done, im betting it is something really simple that im missing. below is the registration.php page and the register.inc.php page, I cant add images as i dont have enough points.

register.php

```
    <?php
//include_once 'includes/register.inc.php';
// define variables and set to empty values
$usernameErr = $emailErr = $passwordErr = $clubnameErr = "";
$username = $email = $password = $clubname = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $username = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
  $clubname = test_input($_POST["clubname"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
    $usernameErr = "**Name is required**";
  } else {
    $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$username)) {
      $usernameErr = "**Only letters and white space allowed**";
      exit();
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "**Email is required**";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
      $emailErr = "**Invalid email format**";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
    $passwordErr = "**Password is required**";
  } else {
    $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
  }

    if (empty($_POST["confirmpassword"])) {
    $confirmpasswordErr = "**Please confirm password**";
  } else {
    $confirmpassword = test_input($_POST["confirmpassword"]);
  }

  if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirmpassword']){
   $confirmpasswordErr = "**Passwords did not match**";
   }

   if($_POST["password"] && strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6)
    {
        $passwordErr = "**Password needs to be at least 6 characters**";
    } 

  if (empty($_POST["clubname"])) {
    $clubnameErr = "**Club Name is required**";
  } else {
    $clubname = test_input($_POST["clubname"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$clubname)) {
      $clubnameErr = "**Only letters and white space allowed**";
    }

    if ($usernameErr == '' && $emailErr == '' && $passwordErr == '' && $confirmpasswordErr == '' && $clubnameErr == '') {
        $clubname;
    header("Location: includes/register.inc.php");
    }
  }
}


//echo $_POST['username'];
//echo $_POST['email'];
//echo $_POST['password'];
//echo $_POST['confirmpassword'];
//echo $_POST['clubname'];
?>



<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#form {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="form">
<form id="registermember" name="registermember" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <div align="center">
          <fieldset>
            <legend style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: large;">Register Members</legend>

            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="33%"><div align="right"><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">Members Name:</span></div></td>
                <td width="33%"><div align="center"><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
                <input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="<?php echo $username;?>" size="40%">
                </span></div>
                <td width="33%"><div align="left"><span class="error" style="color: #FF0004; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $usernameErr;?></span></div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div align="center"><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
                </span></div>              <span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
                  <label for="email">

                  <div align="center">
                    <div align="right"><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">Members Email:</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;"></span><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
                  </label>
                </span></td>
                <td><div align="center"><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
                <input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" size="40%">
                </span></div>          
                <td style="color: #FF0004"><div align="left"><span style="color: #FF0004; font-weight: bold;"><span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span></span></div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div align="center"><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
                </span></div>              <span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
                  <label for="password2">
                  <div align="center">
                    <div align="right"><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">Members Password:</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;"></span><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
                  </label>
                </span></td>
                <td><div align="center"><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
                <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="40%">
                </span></div>          
                <td style="color: #FF0004"><div align="left"><span style="color: #FF0004; font-weight: bold;"><span class="error"><?php echo $passwordErr;?></span></span></div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div align="center"><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
                </span></div>              <span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
                  <label for="confirmpassword">
                  <div align="center">
                    <div align="right"><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">Confirm Password:</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;"></span><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
                  </label>
                </span></td>
                <td><div align="center"><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
                <input name="confirmpassword" type="password" id="confirmpassword" size="40%">
                </span></div>          
                <td style="color: #FF0004"><div align="left"><span style="color: #FF0004; font-weight: bold;"><span class="error"><?php echo $confirmpasswordErr;?></span></span></div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div align="center"><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
                </span></div>              <span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
                  <label for="clubname2">
                  <div align="center">
                    <div align="right"><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">Members Club:</span></div>
                  </div>
                  <span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;"></span><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
                  </label>
                </span></td>
                <td><div align="center"><span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">
                <input name="clubname" type="text" id="clubname" value="<?php echo $clubname;?>" size="40%">
                </span></div>          
                <td style="color: #FF0004"><div align="left"><span style="color: #FF0004; font-weight: bold;"><span class="error"><?php echo $clubnameErr;?></span></span></div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><div align="center">
                  <p>
                    <input name="submitmember" type="submit" id="submitmember" formaction="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" formmethod="POST" value="Add Member">
                  </p>
                </div>                
                <td style="color: #FF0004">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </fieldset>
          </form>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

register.inc.php

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$clubname = $_POST['clubname'];



echo 'success'.'<br/><br/>';
echo $clubname.'<br/><br/>';
echo $username.'<br/><br/>';
echo $email.'<br/><br/>';
echo $password.'<br/><br/>';

?>
```

Comment: Post data is not preserved when you redirect .... Does not work that way.  You should probably be including the register.inc.php file, not redirecting to it.

Comment: I have done that but it echoes straight back to the register page, is there anyway I can stop it doing that?

Comment: I jst tried that, the register.inc.php still wont echo the data except back to the register page

Comment: The reason im doing it this way is to avoid posting the password unhashed, once i know the data gets posted to the register.inc.php page I will hash the password on the register.php page, unless my thinking is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to transfer a data between pages, use `session_start();`  at the begin of the page of register.inc.php and register.php.
Then you can call it on register.inc.php

You need to do this , at this point :

```
if ($usernameErr == '' && $emailErr == '' && $passwordErr == '' && $confirmpasswordErr == '' && $clubnameErr == '') {

    $_SESSION['data'] = array($_POST['username'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['clubname']);
header("Location: includes/register.inc.php");
   //insert post data to session var.
}
```

Then at register.inc.php

```
list($username,$email,$pass,$clubname) = $_SESSION['data'];
unset($_SESSION['data']);

//expand it on list then echo.

echo 'success'.'<br/><br/>';
echo $clubname.'<br/><br/>';
echo $username.'<br/><br/>';
echo $email.'<br/><br/>';
echo $password.'<br/><br/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is write the whole block of code in register.inc.php where you included it and have a die() statement after it.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pass data through url, just like

```
    register.inc.php?name=abcd&email=abcd@gmail.com
```

and use `$_GET['username'];` and `$_GET['email'];` methods in `register.inc.php` to get the data.

Hope this helps.